# Bootstrap navbar-bottom-fixed moving with on screen keyboard on Tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using a bootstrap `navbar-bottom-fixed` for a bottom navigation bar. Whenever I need to input some stuff, the onscreen keyboard is shown and the navbar "floats" toghter with it (is displayed above the keyboard).

Any ideea how I could overcome this? If I could just listen to the keyboard show event I could simply change the css `postion` attribute and I think It will work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if and input is focused with Jquery and then hide the bottom bar if it is.

Like this:

```
$('input').focus( function() {
    $('.navbar-bottom-fixed').hide();
});

$('input').blur( function() {
    $('.navbar-bottom-fixed').show();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, had this solution in mind, but I was hoping there is something more direct then binding listeners to each input. If nothing else comes up as an answer I will mark this as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

I solve it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('head').append('<style>.navbar-fixed-bottom{visibility:hidden}@media (orientation:portrait) and (height:' + $(window).height() + 'px){.navbar-fixed-bottom{visibility:visible}}@media (orientation:portrait) and (height:' + $(window).width() + 'px){.navbar-fixed-bottom{visibility:visible}}@media (orientation:landscape) and (height:' + $(window).width() + 'px){.navbar-fixed-bottom{visibility:visible}}@media (orientation:landscape) and (height:' + $(window).height() + 'px){.navbar-fixed-bottom{visibility:visible}}</style>')
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, this work for me, hide and show trick or toggle position between fixed & absolute are not what I want because when user hit the back button the status of input field are not change ot blur or focusout, we need to click outside the input field, but your css trick solved my problem

Comment: @blizer Hi, maybe this is an old question, but I just used your way. Does this method work on all mobile devices? because I tried it on several mobile devices, there are some devices where the bottom navigation is not showing